# JS случайное значение массива

Tags: javascript

Нужно по нажатию на кнопку присвоить ей(кнопке) backgroundColor на один из цветов радуги. Я сделал это следующим образом

```
function buttonRand() {
var color = ["#FF0000","#FFA500","#FFFF00","#008000", "#87CEEB", "#0000FF"," #8A2BE2"];
var button = document.getElementById('buttonRand');
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
button.style.backgroundColor = '"' + color[i] + '"';}

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button id="buttonRand" onclick="buttonRand()">RAINBOW</button>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку не происходит никаких действий, даже в консоле нет никаких ошибок. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки лишние:

```js
function buttonRand() {
    var color = ["#FF0000","#FFA500","#FFFF00","#008000", "#87CEEB", "#0000FF"," #8A2BE2"];
    var button = document.getElementById('buttonRand');
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
    button.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="buttonRand" onclick="buttonRand()">RAINBOW</button>
</div>
```